# for line in f: why is there a difference when replacing in lists?

Tags: python, loops, replace, line

Don't these two say the exact same thing? Why is it when I run the first one, I end up with just the last item in the list, but I get ["a","b","c"] for the second one?

```
content = ["a\n","b\n","c\n"]

for line in content:
    content = line.replace("\n","")

content = [line.replace("\n","") for line in content]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result = [a_func(elem) for elem in a_list]`

is equivalent to

```
result = []
for elem in a_list:
    result.append(a_func(elem))
```

Therefore, in your example, the **for loop** equivalent to the **list comprehension** is

```
result = []
for line in content:
    result.append(line.replace("\n",""))
```

Answer (score 5):

In the `for` loop you are replacing the name `content` with a *string*. In effect, the last item from the list *content* with the `\n` replaced with `''` will be pointed to by the name `content`.

In the second **list comprehension**, you are creating a *list* with each item of the `content` list with the last character replaced with `''` and assigning the new list to the name `content`.

Answer (score 1):

They don't say the same thing.  In your first example with the `for` loop, on every iteration you assign the name `content` to a single item from the list (`line`, with some text replaced).  `content` is overwritten every time, so only the last element is there at the end.  In the second example, you create an entirely new list and assign that to `content`.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, you update content's value with `line.replace("\n", "")`.  This keeps happening for each element in content.  Since 'c\n' is the last element, the line has the value 'c\n' at the end of your iteration, and you assign that to content.

```
#Trace of loop
#iteration 1: line = "a\n"
content = line.replace("\n","") (which is 'a')
#iteration 2: line = "b\n"
content = line.replace("\n","") (which is 'b')
#iteration 3: line = "c\n"
content = line.replace("\n","") (which is 'c')
```

Thus, content has the value 'c'

The second is a list comprehension, and it means this:

```
[ "a\n".replace("\n",""), "b\n".replace("\n",""), "c\n".replace("\n","") ]
```

(I.e. the first element of this new list is `line.replace("\n","")`, where line takes on the first element of content ("a\n"), and second element of this new list is `line.replace("\n","")`, where line takes on the second element of content ("a\n"), and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

A fixed version which most closely matches your original:

```
content = ["a\n","b\n","c\n"]

for i in range(len(content)):
    content[i] = content[i].replace("\n","")
print content

content = ["a\n","b\n","c\n"]
content = [line.replace("\n","") for line in content]
print content
```

Here the two blocks are equivalent.